# Cant have class in javascript innerHTML

Tags: javascript, function, class, innerhtml

```
<div id="myDiv" class="example">Example Text.</div> <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

I have a function that changes the inner html

```
myFunction() {

  document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML="<ol class="example"><li>Example 1</li><li>Example 2</li><li>Example 3</li></ol>"

}
```

And when i add the class i get an error: unexpected identifier. Why is this? if i have

Comment: Because you should properly escape `example`. Place it in the single quotes.

Comment: Or escape the double quotes: `"<ol class=\"example\">..."`

Comment: It is a javascript error due to use of `"` in the string. Try changing it to `document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML='<ol class="example"><li>Example 1</li><li>Example 2</li><li>Example 3</li></ol>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in javascript , both "" and '' are valid for strings , but what happens if we do want to use "" or '' inside a string?

`var str = "he said to me 'hi'"`

there is no problem, as long the nested character (" or ') is different from the outer character (' or " respectivly)

so in your example :

```
myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML="<ol class='example'><li>Example 1</li><li>Example 2</li><li>Example 3</li></ol>"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes '' for setting the class. If you use double quotes "" within double quotes you will get the problem you are experiencing.

```
myFunction() {

  document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML="<ol class='example'><li>Example 1</li><li>Example 2</li><li>Example 3</li></ol>"

}
```

Comment: Downvoted; this question was asked bunch of times, better flag it as dupe, not answer :/

Answer (score 0):

Dont use "" inside "" without \ and you forgot to type function before myFunction()

```
<div id="myDiv" class="example">Example Text.</div> <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

.

```
function myFunction() {

  document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML="<ol class='example'><li>Example 1</li><li>Example 2</li><li>Example 3</li></ol>";

}
```